# JSON Parse Error (no experience of JSON)

Tags: php, javascript, json, parsing, yui

I have to move a system from one server to another, and I'm coming across an error when trying to access this page. The code is exactly the same as the live, working system, yet it doesn't work now for some reason.

JS Code that pulls up the error:

```
var loadData = function(data) {
if(data)
    data += '&offset=' + offset;
else
    data = 'offset=' + offset;

var callback = {
    success: function(o) {
        try {
            var data = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(o.responseText);
        } catch(e) { alert('e: ' + e + '\no: ' + o + '\ndata: ' + data + '\noffset: ' + offset + '\n Response Text:' + o.responseText); }

        // removed a lot of pointless code (no error here)
}

YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'json/dmrlist.php', callback, data);
}
```

This is printed out from the alert:

[image]

This is the (start of) the php code that it is "calling", yet there is an error as seen on the screenshot.

```
line 6: $JSON = json_decode($_POST['JSON']);

line 8: if($JSON->Depot)
line 9:     $filter = " AND `Site` = '" . $JSON->Depot . "'";
```

Basically, $JSON is undefined, which means nothing is posted, but it looks like the javascript is meant to be posting the information to it?

I'm so confused, I have no experience with JSON or javascript, and can't figure out why this won't work.

Comment: Post the text you are trying to decode with json_decode.. otherwise we can guess all day long what's wrong.

Comment: That's what I don't understand, it's not my system and its trying to get $_POST['json'] and I don't know where that data is meant to be coming from. Sorry, no experience with this

Comment: Looks like you have a PHP error that's causing the `o.responseText` to contain error messages instead of JSON, which is in turn causing a JSON parser error.

Comment: Yeah I think that's because the PHP page is trying to decode json data but it hasn't recieved it from $_POST['JSON'], yet the only thing that pulls up the page (dmrlist.php) is the javascript function shown `(YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'json/dmrlist.php', callback, data);)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data variable is going to be sent to the server, but probably just as key/value pairs.  You can try dumping them out like:

```
if (isset($_POST['JSON'])) {
    print_r($_POST['JSON']);
}
if (isset($_POST['Depot']) {
    print_r($_POST['JSON']);
}
```

Or just 
    print_r( $_POST );

I suspect that $_POST['JSON'] is not set and you probably don't need to decode the other values as JSON as they are probably just key/value pairs that you can read straight from the $_POST array, but I'm not familiar with YUI's ajax functions so I could be wrong - check the values on the server.

P.S. Using the print_r this way will result in invalid return (it won't be JSON), but you will be able to look at it in Firebug, etc. and see the values.

Comment: Where would I put that code? I can't put it on dmrlist.php because that isn't meant to be accessed on its own as it won't have anything posted, only meant to be accessed by the YUI AJAX function

Comment: You should either put it in dmrlist.php (temporarily) or create a copy and use that (just change the client side code to point to it).  You should also be able to see the request variables in something like Firebug, Fiddler, etc... and check to see if there is a parameter named JSON and if it looks to be json format.  From your code posting I suspect there is not such a variable, or its empty.

Comment: I think it is empty too, the only problem is that I don't know what is supposed to populate it, or "post" data to the page for it to get. The only place in the entire code base that references dmrlist.php is the YUI AJAX function shown above, so I figured that must be somehow sending the data (or not in this case)

Comment: Yeah, its sending something or your wouldn't be getting anything back, even an error. Hopefully you have someplace to run the code on that's not live, even if its just copying the files to a new name, or using the error_log() function in php to dump info to a log file.  Basically, you're going to have to reverse engineer what the PHP expects by inspecting the code and checking its behavior, then either modify the PHP or the JS or both to work together.

Comment: I'm relatively sure nothing is inside $_POST['JSON'], I tried sending the value to an error log and got nothing, yet when I send something simple like the URL referer, it prints it

Comment: I posted my fix below if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the old server is using an old version of php, and as such doesn't seem to need "ifsets" (I'm not sure why) but I just put `if(isset($_POST['JSON'])){` before the code that handled the JSON, and now its working. I'm assuming for the first loop nothing is posted, so nothing can be recieved, but the ifset lets php skip the JSON code and get to the first select from db, which can then be looped back, this time `$_POST['JSON']` is actually set.

TL;DR: **Old version of PHP, just needed to put an ifset in, and declare a variable**